# Fitting image perfectly on the page

Tags: html, css, image

I did some search here and tried different codes that was recommended but none seems to work. Sorry if this is a basic question but I'm very new to coding.
I'm trying to centre and fit an image to the browser window. What code do i need to use? 
P.S the image isn't my background image. I'm changing the color of the background and want this image on top of the background image.
This is the code i have

```
<body>
<div id="clock">
  <img src="images/clock.png" alt="">
</div>
</body>
```

What CSS code do i need to use to achieve what I'm trying to do? 
The first image is how its showing on the browser (basically can only see part of the image since it's enlarged)
The second image is how I want it to look

[image: this is how its showing]

[image: second picture is how i want it]

Answer (score 0):

Add some styling for that image. Add this to your css file:

```
#clock img{
   width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this may help you

```
#clock
{
    margin:0px auto;
    text-align:center;
}
#clock
{
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#clock{
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}

#clock img{
height:100px;
  width:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="clock">
<img src="http://pngimg.com/upload/clock_PNG6611.png">

</div>
```

here you can increase or decrease image height:100px; but make sure width is auto otherwise the aspect ratio of that image will effect